# Clone nodes and relationships with Cypher

Tags: neo4j

Is it possible to clone arbitrary nodes and relationships in a single Cypher neo4j 2.0 query?
'Arbitrary' reads 'without specifying their labels and relationship types'. Something like:

```
MATCH (node1:NodeType)-[e]->(n)
CREATE (clone: labels(n)) set clone=n set clone.prop=1 
CREATE (node1)-[e1:type(e)]->(clone) set e1=e set e1.prop=2
```

is not valid in Cypher, so one cannot simply get labels from one node or relationship and assign them to another, because labels are compiled into the query literally.

Sure, labels and relation types are important for MATCH and WHERE for producing effective query plan, but isn't CREATE making another case?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to clone parts of a graph is to use the [`dump` command in Neo4j shell](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/shell-commands.html#_dumping_the_database_or_a_cypher_result_to_cypher_statements). `dump` generates cypher `create` statements from your `return` clauses. The result of dump can be appied to the graph database to create clones.

Comment: I am trying to do this exact same thing. Turns out the dump file saves all relationships by source and destination node numbers, but when applying the Cypher script generated by dump, neo4j does not take into account node IDs that are hardcoded in the Cypher code and it regenerates them. This ends up breaking all the relationships. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: The `dump` command does not emit internal node id's. Node id's are a implementation detail.

Comment: is there a way of excuting the dump command into file, and not to the console?

Comment: `echo "dump" | bin/neo4j-shell > output.cypher`

Answer (score 1):

Today, April 2022, I believe the best approach might be using an [APOC procedure](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.3/graph-updates/graph-refactoring/clone-subgraph/)

I had a similar requirement and this worked for me.

```
MATCH  (rootA:Root{name:'A'}),
       (rootB:Root{name:'B'})
MATCH path = (rootA)-[:LINK*]->(node)
WITH rootA, rootB, collect(path) as paths
CALL apoc.refactor.cloneSubgraphFromPaths(paths, {
    standinNodes:[[rootA, rootB]]
})
YIELD input, output, error
RETURN input, output, error
```