# How do I clone a sub tree for a node, what would be the easiest and fastest way to do that?

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

Here is the code I am working on:

```
def NodeExists(type_name, relationship_name):

    query_string = "MATCH (a)-[:%s]->(c) WHERE a.name = {y} RETURN {parent:a.name,child:{name:collect(c.name)}}"%(relationship_name)
    return graph.run(query_string, {"y":type_name}).data()
```

I don't know how to add a copy of the resulting tree into a different tree under different node using `py2neo`

Comment: Your function is returning a list of dictionaries, not a "tree". Can you be more specific about what your are trying to do?

Comment: @cybersam yup thats just for display purpose, I can also return a cursor type, but would that help?

can I pass cursor to py2neo create() and would it create a entire new copy of that tree?

Comment: Are you trying to create new nodes? Are they exact clones of existing nodes, or somehow different? You need to provide full details about what you are trying to do.

Comment: @cybersam
`  copy of the resulting tree into a different tree under different node `
yes an exact copy and not a referenced value, under a new node in a completely different tree

really any sort of help or direction would be helpful

Comment: This might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779579/clone-nodes-and-relationships-with-cypher

Comment: @cybersam even that hasn't be answered,

I just want a way of creating tree using ` records `or ` dictionaries`  returned by a query

Comment: also I am using py2neo v4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirmed this with the Neo4j team,

**There is no current way of cloning a subgraph**